# My TF2 server cannot connect to the item server

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, hosting, sourcemod

I own a standard SRCDS server and when I (or anybody else) joins, they cannot connect to the item server.

I have checked other servers and it definitely works there.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to my previous answer and the [error log shown there](http://puu.sh/nSBhH/16f01ee426.png), the version of SteamTools you're using is [out of date](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=278413).

[Updating to a newer version](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showpost.php?p=1584128&postcount=1) should fix the problem.

Comment: I linked to the page that has links to the newest builds instead of to the newest builds directly.  This is so that this answer remains relevant when even newer versions come out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a firewall, make sure you have all the correct ports open.

TF2 SRCDS uses the following ports by default:

- UDP 27015 - Clients send queries for info about your server on this port. Adjustable using `-port`
- TCP 27015 - RCON (Remote Console) uses this port. Adjustable using `-port` (it's always the same port as the previous port)
- UDP 27005 - Clients connect to the game on this port. Adjustable using `-clientport`
- UDP 27025 - SRCDS binds this port for SourceTV (even if you don't have SourceTV on) unless you specify `-nohltv`. Adjustable using `+tv_port`
- UDP 26901 - The server talks to Steam's servers on this port.  Adjustable using `-sport`, although it *actually* uses the port **one higher** than you specify (default is 26900).

By the sound of it, port 26901 is being blocked.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have forwarded all those ports and the firewall is not blocking any of them, yet it is still unable to connect to the items server. Here is the console log: http://puu.sh/nSBhH/16f01ee426.png

Comment: @SydLambert By any chance, do you have the SourceMod SteamTools extension installed on this server?

Comment: Yes. Could that be the problem? @Powerlord

Comment: @SydLambert Yes.  Sorry about not getting back to you sooner.  I took a "short" nap that ended up being 4 hours long.  I've posted a new answer about it.